# In a set of data, need to pick correct dates based on relativity to todays date

Tags: excel, date

```
X   9/1/2015,
X   9/3/2016,
X   10/1/2017,
Y   9/3/2015,
Y   9/1/2017,
Z   9/1/2014,
Z   9/1/2015,
Z   9/2/2016,
A   10/15/2015,
A   11/1/2015,
A   10/20/2016
```

In the first column are identifiers with different dates in the second column. What I need is pull out only the relevant dates. The relative dates are the current and future. The future date is the date in the first date that comes a decent amount of time in the future:

```
X   9/3/2016
Y   9/1/2017
Z   9/2/2016
A   10/20/2016
```

The current date is the "later one closest to today's date":

```
X   9/1/2015
Y   9/3/2015
Z   9/1/2015
A   11/1/2015
```

So for A, it would be the 11/1 date because by the time it is loaded and seen by the customer, that date will be here (generally about one month).

My question is that I need a formula that can tell me which values I want to keep and which I don't (also known as 'keep the current and future').

I made formulas that would help give me the answer given that no date is in the past by using a COUNTIF in column C on the amount of unique values in column A and then using `=IF(OR(AND(C2>=3,A2=A3),(C2<3)),1,0)`, but this won't work if I want to keep the second and third dates because the first is past.

Comment: Basically all I need is to know which ones I want and which ones I don't... a 1 for keep and a 0 for don't is good enough. The macro I will create with the whole file will get rid of the lines with 0.

Comment: No. For example, if there is a date of 10/1/2016 and 10/1/2017, I would only want the 10/1/2016... we call the 2017 date the "future future" and we only want the "closest future" to todays date. Sorry if that is confusing.

Comment: Essentially  we are loading authorization files, and the customer wants to be able to see what their current authorizations are and what their authorizations are going to be when they next change.

Comment: So, if the dates were 10/15/2015, 10/20/2015, 4/1/2016, 11/20/2016, and 10/10/2017, we would want 10/20/2015 since that is going to be loaded in 2 days and 4/1/2016 since that is going to be the next authorization load we do for them

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure I figured it out in potentially the most ugly fashion possible... Here is what I got:

Need two blank rows at top of the sheet (data starting in B3 and dates in C3, have a unrelated formula in A3).

Formula in D3 finds the first value, I want to keep given the rows are custom sorted by column B and then C:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B3=B4,B3=B5,(TODAY()-C3)>0,(TODAY()-C4)>0,(TODAY()-C3)<(TODAY()-C4)),AND(B3=B4,B3=B5,(TODAY()-C3)<0),AND(B3=B2,B3=B1,(TODAY()-C3)>0),AND(B3=B4,B3=B5,(TODAY()-C3)>0,(TODAY()-C4)<0),AND(B3=B2,B3=B4,(TODAY()-C3)>0,(TODAY()-C2)>0,(TODAY()-C4)<0),AND(B3=B2,B3=B4,(TODAY()-C3)>0,(TODAY()-C2)>0,(TODAY()-C4)>0,(TODAY()-C3)<(TODAY()-C2),(TODAY()-C3)<(TODAY()-C4)),AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B3)=2,B3=B2,(TODAY()-C3)>0),AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B3)=2,B3=B2,(TODAY()-C3)<0,(TODAY()-C2)>0),AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B3)=2,B3=B4,(TODAY()-C3)>0,(TODAY()-C4)<0),AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B3)=2,B3=B4,(TODAY()-C3)<0),(COUNTIF(B:B,B3)=1)),1,0)
```

Formula in E3 finds the next date I want for column A values that are equal, and pulls the initial date over. I will vLookup from this column to my other sheets. It tells me which values to keep:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B3=B2,B3=B1,D2=1,D1<>1),AND(B3=B2,B3=B4,D2=1),(D3=1)),1,0)
```

I couldn't figure out an easier way to do this, so I essentially used a giant =if(or( statement ) ) to go through every scenario. In which I would want to keep the "current" date, and the next formula decides which is the future based on that.